# why array store duplicate value while iteration object inside the object ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store object property value inside the array .I have objects inside a object .I need to store `skey` property inside the array.But I tried like this

```
var obj ={
aa:{
name:"test"
},
bb:{
name:"test",
skey:"ctr+d"
},
cc:{
name:"test",
skey:"ctr+m"
},
dd:{
name:"test"
}

}
var newArray=[]
for (var key in obj) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    var ob = obj[key];
    for (var prop in ob) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(ob.hasOwnProperty('skey')){
        newArray.push(ob.skey)
        }

     }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x4ra3yso/3/
It add dublicate item in array .

My expected outtput is this

```
**['ctr+d','ctr+m']**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for...in` loop to loop objects and if `skey` property exists inside current object push it into array

```js
var obj = {
  aa: {name: "test"},
  bb: {name: "test",skey: "ctr+d"},
  cc: {name: "test",skey: "ctr+m"},
  dd: {name: "test"}
}, result = [];

for (var p in obj) {
  if (obj[p].skey) result.push(obj[p].skey);
}

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `Object.keys` and `reduce`

```js
var obj = {
  aa: {name: "test"},
  bb: {name: "test",skey: "ctr+d"},
  cc: {name: "test",skey: "ctr+m"},
  dd: {name: "test"}
}

obj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(sum, el) {
  if(obj[el].skey) sum = sum.concat(obj[el].skey);
  return sum;
}, [])

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
var obj ={
  aa:{
    name:"test"
  },
  bb:{
    name:"test",
    skey:"ctr+d"
  },
  cc:{
    name:"test",
    skey:"ctr+m"
  },
  dd:{
    name:"test"
  }    
}

var newArray=[]
for (var key in obj) {
    var ob = obj[key];

    if(ob.hasOwnProperty('skey')){
      newArray.push(ob.skey)
    }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

or if you want to keep the same logic :

```
var newArray=[]
for (var key in obj) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    var ob = obj[key];
    for (var prop in ob) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(prop === 'skey'){
          newArray.push(ob['skey'])
        }

     }
}

console.log(newArray)
```